# while loop in shell script

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I am able to run count command but when I use it in while condition, it is giving error:

```
-bash: [/usr/bin/ps -aef|/usr/bin/egrep 'catalina|java|wrapper-linux-x86-64'|/usr/bin/grep -v 'catalina|java|wrapper-linux-x86-64'|wc -l: No such file or directory.


count="/usr/bin/ps -aef|/usr/bin/egrep 'catalina|java|wrapper-linux-x86- 
64'|/usr/bin/grep -v 'catalina|java|wrapper-linux-x86-64'|wc -l"
while [ "$count" -ne 0 ]
do
echo "killing services and tomcat process"
/usr/bin/ps -aef|/usr/bin/egrep "catalina|java|wrapper-linux-x86- 
64"|/usr/bin/grep -v "catalina|java"|/usr/bin/awk '{print 
$2}'|/usr/bin/xargs kill -9
sleep 10
count="/usr/bin/ps -aef|/usr/bin/egrep 'catalina|java|wrapper-linux-x86- 
64'|/usr/bin/grep -v 'catalina|java|wrapper-linux-x86-64'|wc -l"

done;
```

Comment: See `pgrep -fc 'catalina|java|wrapper-linux-x86-64'` to count the number of processes with those strings in their arg list.

Comment: Use https://shellcheck.net/ to spot and help fix syntax errors

Answer (score 3):

```
count="/usr/bin/ps -aef|...|wc -l"
```

Don't store commands in variables, they're not made for that and using the stored command is difficult. If you want to store the command somewhere, use a function instead:

```
count_procs() {
    /usr/bin/ps -aef|...|wc -l
}
```

A function can be used like any other command.

The code you've shown will compare the value of that string in `count` against zero as an integer. Bash's `[` would complain about a non-numeric value.

The error you presented would come from a command like `["$count" -eq 0 ]` (without a space between `[` and `$count`), since in that case, the contents of `count` are concatenated with `[` to form the first word of the command line, the name of the command to run. While it would be silly to do so, it's entirely possible to have a path that contains brackets, pipe characters and white space.

Now, assuming that you want to actually run the command and capture its output to compare against zero, you'll need to use command substitution `$(...)`:

```
result=$(ps ... |wc -l)            # save the output of the command to `result`
```

or

```
[ "$(ps ... | wc -l)" -eq 0 ] ... # use the command output directly in a test
```

Assuming you want to count the processes every time the loop runs, you'll have to 
run the command within the loop body. So, e.g.

```
while [ "$(ps ... | wc -l)" -eq 0 ]; do
    ...
done
```

or, with a function

```
count_procs() {
    /usr/bin/ps -aef|...|wc -l
}
while [ "$(count_procs)" -eq 0 ]; do
    ...
done
```

Just counting the processes once before the loop would make the condition a constant, and the loop would repeat indefinitely, or not at all.

Answer (score 2):

In your while loop, you need to decrement your count variable.

```
count=10
while [ $count -ne 0 ]; do
    echo "Count is $count"
    ((count--))
done
```

For the actual arithmetic, there are a number of ways to do it, such as:

- `((count--))`
- `((count-=1))`
- `((count=count-1))`
- `count=$((count - 1))`

For more info on double parentheses constructs, see: https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/dblparens.html

You could also use `let`:

- `let "count--"`
- `let "count-=1"`
- `let "count=count-1"`

For more info on `let`, see: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/let

---

**Edit**: A note on POSIX compliant shells that don't have the same fancy features as `bash`.

Posix shells can use the `$(( <expression> ))` syntax.  So if you had the same loop above, and you wanted to ensure it would work on a shell like `ksh`, or officially portable shell like CAE Issue 4 (XPG4)'s `sh`:

- `count=$((count - 1))`

Using this syntax will make your script more portable than using bash specific syntax, if that matters to you.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @Vlastimil, that's a good idea.  Since `bash` is mentioned in the question, that's how the answer was written.  But I'll add a note about arithmetic in POSIX shells.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the confusion about command substitution quoting, the error message indicates you actually have `while ["$count" -ne 0]` without the required space around the brackets. Keep in mind that the the part after "while" is actually a *command*, and the loop ends when the *command* exits with a non-zero status (ref https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Looping-Constructs).

Due to the missing space, bash sees

```
while ["/usr/bin/ps -aef|/usr/bin/egrep 'catalina|java|wrapper-linux-x86-64'|/usr/bin/grep -v 'catalina|java|wrapper-linux-x86-64'|wc -l" -ne 0]
```

and it is trying to execute the **command** `["/usr/bin/ps -aef|...|wc -l"` which is obviously not found

It is important to remember that `[` is actually a **command** and therefore a space after it is required to separate the command name from its first argument. (same reason you write `ls -l` and not `ls-l`). Also the `[` command requires that `]` is its *last* argument, so `]` also needs whitespace separation.

At a bash prompt, type `help [` and `help test` (and also `help [[`)

Answer (score 1):

Simpler:

```
while pkill -f 'catalina|java|wrapper-linux-x86-64'; do 
  sleep 10
done
```

Still unsafe to kill processes based on their arg list.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem being usage of double quotes where there shall be:

```
$(...)
```

---

I have a few remarks to this part (too long for a comment):

> ```
> while [ "$count" -ne 0 ]
> do
> echo "killing services and tomcat process"
> done;
> ```

---

- There is no stopping mechanism for the `while` loop like:

  ```
  count=$(( count - 1 ))
  ```
- From a styling point, you *should* space the inner part.
- Just to note, you don't need a semicolon at the end.

Comment: i am killing processes so count number would decrease, that part of code i didnt include in my question

Answer (score -1):

replace

```
count="..."
```

with

```
count=`...`
```

Comment: Please avoid this construct in favor for `$(...)`.